# ng-init only if value is null/undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to use `ng-init` so that it is only run if the value in `ng-model` is null or undefined?

I have this input

```
<input ng-model="entry.Value.Currency" type="text" placeholder="Currency">
```

I would like the `"Currency"` value to be set to 'USD' if `entry.Value.Currency == null`. Note that it could contain a completly different value like `'EUR'` in which case I want the code to do nothing.

As it is now whatever I type in the field just gets deleted, which I think is because `.Currency` does not exist / is undefined. If it helps the value of `entry.Value` is always guaranteed to exist / not be null.

Tried adding `ng-init="entry.Value.Currency ='USD'"` to the input field but that did not seem to do anything at all.

I would like to accomplish this without initializing the `Currency` variable in javascript as inputs can be added dynamically and what values they add to `entry.Value` may differ. The only thing I know for each input control is that `entry.Value = {};`

Comment: You mean something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/15qgxge5/) Obviously, with your requirements, it could be made into a directive

Comment: @George that seems pretty much like what I want, guess I'm going to have to learn how to write an angular directive so I can make it more general like you suggested :)

Comment: Isn't simply `placeholder="{{condition ? 'Currency': 'USD'}}"` a choice?

Comment: @tanmay As far as I know placeholder is removed when I click the field, and then the "Currency" value is still set to null. I would like to set the Currency value to "USD" if Currency is null or undefined.

Comment: @JensB oops! inspired by the answer below, I though you want placeholder there.. sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would suit you best is a directive that uses the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

I've written one that should do what you want, the code for it is

```
myApp.directive('currencyInit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        if (ngModel.$modelValue == undefined || ngModel.$modelValue == null) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue('USD');
        }
        element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
      }  
    }
  }
});
```

And to see it in action you can look at this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/15qgxge5/4/)

P.S. Sorry I took so long to write it I went out for lunch

Comment: Thank you. I just made a minor modificaiton to this so that I could set the default value in the attribue like this `value-init="USD"`. http://jsfiddle.net/fqzvoxt2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-attr-placeholder="{{!entry.Value.currency?'USD':'something'}}"`

Comment: Wouldn't this just change the placeholder for the input and not that actual value?

Comment: @George reading the documentation it seems that way. Giving it a try anyways....  Did not work. Just editing the placeholder.